# IntelliJ ClassNotFound Exception

Tags: java, intellij-idea, libgdx

So I've been trying to successfully import and run a `libgdx` project on `IntelliJ Idea`. But I am running into this error. I can't figure out why. There are multiple answers online but my problem does not seem to be like solved by any of the solutions I could find.

The problem is that, as you know , libgdx creates a specific module for your project to be run on different environments(ios, android, desktop). I run into a problem when trying run the desktop module. It gives the following error. I posted it here :

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\bin\java" -Didea.launcher.port=7535 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 15.0.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Users\Omer\Desktop\Game Projects\ATS\desktop\build\resources\main;C:\Users\Omer\Desktop\Game Projects\ATS\core\build\classes\main;C:\Users\Omer\Desktop\Game Projects\ATS\core\build\resources\main;C:\Users\Omer\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.badlogicgames.gdx\gdx\1.7.1\2179cc613447c297623a4a6d2ba6692c3aaff804\gdx-1.7.1.jar;C:\Users\Omer\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.badlogicgames.gdx\gdx-box2d\1.7.1\fd23897393900f8f888222795e3229eff600fb3d\gdx-box2d-1.7.1.jar;C:\Users\Omer\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.badlogicgames.gdx\gdx-backend-lwjgl\1.7.1\d4531b364d1c2513cb99e7bdd9515ae317007cf5\gdx-backend-lwjgl-1.7.1.jar;C:\Users\Omer\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.badlogicgames.gdx\gdx-platform\1.7.1\5cf3464f2b86da3534f6f5e3020bc303db3c4202\gdx-platform-1.7.1-natives-desktop.jar;C:\Users\Omer\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.badlogicgames.gdx\gdx-box2d-platform\1.7.1\6c9c371807914fcf8b354bb51ab67af2a4fda2dc\gdx-box2d-platform-1.7.1-natives-desktop.jar;C:\Users\Omer\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.lwjgl.lwjgl\lwjgl\2.9.2\a9d80fe5935c7a9149f6584d9777cfd471f65489\lwjgl-2.9.2.jar;C:\Users\Omer\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.lwjgl.lwjgl\lwjgl_util\2.9.2\4b9e37300a87799856e0bd15ed81663cdb6b0947\lwjgl_util-2.9.2.jar;C:\Users\Omer\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.badlogicgames.jlayer\jlayer\1.0.1-gdx\7cca83cec5c1b2f011362f4d85aabd71a73b049d\jlayer-1.0.1-gdx.jar;C:\Users\Omer\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jcraft\jorbis\0.0.17\8872d22b293e8f5d7d56ff92be966e6dc28ebdc6\jorbis-0.0.17.jar;C:\Users\Omer\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.lwjgl.lwjgl\lwjgl-platform\2.9.2\510c7d317f5e9e700b9cfaac5fd38bdebf0702e0\lwjgl-platform-2.9.2-natives-windows.jar;C:\Users\Omer\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.lwjgl.lwjgl\lwjgl-platform\2.9.2\d276cdf61fe2b516c7b7f4aa1b8dea91dbdc8d56\lwjgl-platform-2.9.2-natives-linux.jar;C:\Users\Omer\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.lwjgl.lwjgl\lwjgl-platform\2.9.2\d55b46b40b40249d627a83a7f7f22649709d70c3\lwjgl-platform-2.9.2-natives-osx.jar;C:\Users\Omer\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\net.java.jinput\jinput\2.0.5\39c7796b469a600f72380316f6b1f11db6c2c7c4\jinput-2.0.5.jar;C:\Users\Omer\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\net.java.jutils\jutils\1.0.0\e12fe1fda814bd348c1579329c86943d2cd3c6a6\jutils-1.0.0.jar;C:\Users\Omer\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\net.java.jinput\jinput-platform\2.0.5\7ff832a6eb9ab6a767f1ade2b548092d0fa64795\jinput-platform-2.0.5-natives-linux.jar;C:\Users\Omer\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\net.java.jinput\jinput-platform\2.0.5\385ee093e01f587f30ee1c8a2ee7d408fd732e16\jinput-platform-2.0.5-natives-windows.jar;C:\Users\Omer\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\net.java.jinput\jinput-platform\2.0.5\53f9c919f34d2ca9de8c51fc4e1e8282029a9232\jinput-platform-2.0.5-natives-osx.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 15.0.1\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain DesktopLauncher



Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: DesktopLauncher
```

The weird thing is, I tried to run it on Eclipse after having set my eclipse environment with gradle and other required plugins. Eclipse popped a similar error such as "Could not find main class". So what am I doing wrong? I actually followed a tutorial I found online and followed it step by step and still can't figure out what the problem is. The code compiles but does not run. The android module runs perfectly fine. The problem occurs when I try to run the desktop module.

In case anyone wants to see the code:

```
    public class DesktopLauncher {
    public static void main (String[] arg) {
        LwjglApplicationConfiguration config = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
        new LwjglApplication(new atsmain(), config);
    }
}
```

A few things that I noticed to be off :

1. The code builds and compiles. But when I try to manually sync gradle, it tries to look for a java home that is outside of the project sdk location determined by me and from that point on, nothing compiles. so I have to uninstall and install intellij again.
2. If I change anything in the "build.gradle" file of the desktop module, the project needs to be synced which is normal. But then it leads the above mentioned issue.

I am using IntelliJ Community Edition. I tried both 32 and 64 bit versions.

So if anyone can help me figure this out, I'd appreciate it.

Thanks

EDIT:
[image]

Comment: In IntelliJ, go to the Run menu, then choose Edit Configurations. Click your desktop configuration in the left panel and paste a screenshot link here. The problem is likely in this window.

Comment: I just posted it. I don't think the issue is there though.

Answer (score 0):

Your main class appears to be incorrect. It should be something like

com.example.mytestapp.desktop.DesktopLauncher

Click the browse button (3 dots) next to main class, choose project tab, and then browse to the desktop->src->domainstuff->DesktopLauncher

Hopefully that will fix it.

John

Edit :

Just had a thought - you might be using IntelliJ 15.01. There's a nasty bug in it which causes the above main class hassle. See here in the forums at 
[bad logic](http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=21148&p=87780&hilit=intellij#p87780)
Do the import with a v14 IntelliJ and then just open the project in 15.01

John